# Why does the CNN model accuracy vary too much when the dataset is the same?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, tensorflow

I have been working on a project where I have a lot of time series data(3000 csv file) from 6 different devices and I am trying to convert those data to an image array so that I can use them in CNN to do a classification task. My goal is to train the model with existing data and then predict from which device the data came from. As the first experiments, I have decided to classify between two devices and picked 100 files each from both devices.
I have converted all the data to an image array and it looks like the following image:
[image]

below is the code to convert them to image array and my CNN model

```
#Converting to numpy array      
X = np.array(device_list)
y = np.array(device_label)

#Train test split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size= 0.30,random_state=0)

#Adding 1 dimension for grayscale image
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],14,100,1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0],14,100,1)

#scaling data from 0 to 1
X_train_scaled = X_train/36 #Max voltage value 36
X_test_scaled = X_test/36

#Buiding a model
model_2 = tf.keras.Sequential([

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding="same", activation="relu",input_shape=(X_train_scaled[0].shape)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2),    
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(6,3, padding="same", activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(12,3, padding="same", activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2),
     
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(72, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(36, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation= 'softmax') #Output layer
])
#Training the model
model_2.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])             
model_2.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=300)

#Accuracy and loss
loss, accuracy= model_2.evaluate(X_test_scaled, y_test)
print(f'Loss: {loss}, Accuracy: {accuracy}')
```

It needs to mentioned here the image size is not square but 14x100 pixel. Each image is of the same size. After adding 1 dimension the shape of the data:

[image]

The model summary is shown below:

[image]

In my code I have used sklearn train test split package and used `random_state=0` and `42` both. But the problem is I am getting varying range of accuracy starting from 50% to 100% even. If I run the model like 10-15 times then I will almost get varying accuracy from 50% to 100%. Since the my data is same and I have used `random_state=0` and `42` which keeps train and test set same for different run, then why I am having such kind of different accuracy.
Different accuray:
[image] [image]
If the accurcy of the model is low, that is not a problem but if the accuracy is not stable that is a problem. Could someone tell me if there is anything wrong with my model, if there is any mistake with the coding or any kind suggestion on how can I fix this issue?